# Ember.js throws "has no method" errors when running class methods

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a situation where I would like to [reload](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload) the model when a user presses a refresh button. I've implemented this before with Ember-Model, however, we recently moved to Ember-Data and I'm receiving an error when trying to run any [method](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload) from the model class. Any help would be appreciated.

The error when clicking the button:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reload'
```

The application's structure:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.DjangoRESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/1'
});

App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('publishable');
  },
});

App.SomeModel = DS.Model.extend({
  title: attr(),
  description: attr(),

  authors: hasMany('author', { async: true }),
  category: belongsTo('page', { async: true }),

  published: attr(),
  publish_from: attr(),
  slug: attr(),

  contentType: attr(),
});

App.SomeController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions : {
    reload: function(model) {
      model.reload();
    }
  }
});

<div>
  <span {{action reload model}} class="btn"></span>
</div>
```

When I log `this.get('model')` within the action on the controller. I receive the following:

```
Class {type: function, content: (...), store: Class, isLoaded: true, isUpdating: false…}
__ember1390344611587: "ember592"
__ember1390344611587_meta: Object
_super: undefined
arrangedContent: (...)
content: (...)
get content: function () {
set content: function (value) {
isLoaded: true
isUpdating: false
store: Class
toString: function () { return ret; }
type: App.Publishable
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: It's likely that the object you're getting just isn't an instance of `DS.Model`. You should debug your code to find out what it really is. As a side note, your relationships are asynchronous, so trying to `get` them returns a promise, not a model. That might be your issue.

Comment: It may also help you to use `Ember.inspect(model)` to see what object you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reload` exists on individual records, not on record arrays.

Just to be complete, reload also doesn't exist on promises, if it's a promise you need to `then(...)` it to get the real record (this is true of async relationships).

```
promise.then(function(record){
  record.reload();
});
```

Comment: Any idea how I would reload a model than?

Comment: if it's the collection, which I think it is, you'll want to iterate the collection and reload each model.  If you don't feel like doing this you can unload all of the records in store for that type and call find again, which might be simpler.  Is it a collection of records?

Comment: Yeah, it's a collection of posts.